# Wait for autolayout to perform UIView animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have an `UIView` that is loaded from its .xib file and I'd like to perform the animation right when the view is shown.

I want to copy an `ImageView` and perform the animation using that copy, the problem is that since I'm calling the animation within `willMove(toWindow:)` method, the copied `ImageView` frame is created before the autolayout resulting in a weird behavior.

I've tried calling `layoutIfNeeded()` before the animation but with this, the animation isn't performed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to show more details with source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right when the view is shown?
try managing the `UIView` via a `UIViewController` and perform the animation in [`func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621423-viewdidappear) inside your viewController

an example here below how to insert the `uiView` managed in a new `UIViewController` in current viewController's view:

```
self.view.addSubview(myNewViewControler.view)
```

then in the `NewViewController` you can call back the current presented viewController in the `viewDidAppear` via delegate and finally perform animation

Comment: I'd like to avoid presenting a new `UIViewController` since it's a very simple `UIView`

Comment: you don't have to "present" a new UIViewController, you have to manage the subview as a viewController

Comment: Hi @ddb, couldn't work on it until today but I don't know if I'm understanding it. I have a viewControllerA where I show my UIView (that should be controlled with viewControllerB) but since I've never done it I can't figure out what steps to follow, could you guide me please?

Comment: 1. you should create a new ViewControllerB with XIB, then you should put and model the UIView in the ViewControllerB's xib

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149103/discussion-between-ddb-and-idec).